# HTML validation/fix in C#

Tags: c#, html, validation, repair

I need to check if a HTML document is correct, if all tags and attributes are ok (in C#). If not, try to fix malformed tags and/or attributes. Any suggestions for a library or tool that i can use?

Thanks.

Comment: You should start by looking at the [HTML Agility Pack](http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/)

Comment: Whilst the HtmlAgilityPack will parse and show errors it does not as far as I have been able to find out, Fix them for you. Therefore, I have also been looking at TidyManaged. However, I cant get it to run or work on a 64bit .net 4.5 environment it just says "An attempt was made to load a program with an incorrect format. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8007000B)" - Any pointers as to what to do?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[Tidy Managed](http://github.com/markbeaton/TidyManaged) solved my problems. This tool knows to repair broken tags and to close tags. Build TidyManaged app and download the libtidy.dll file and place it in bin/debug file.